# Combining multiple ULs into one UL

Tags: jquery

How can I combine multiple `ul`s into one `ul`?

For example how can i Combine the following.

```
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

To something like this

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
​
```

​

Comment: Does it have to be sorted? Otherwise you only need to remove the </ul> and <ul> between...

Comment: in order would be helpful @jtheman

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The great thing about [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) is that they will move existing DOM elements instead of copying them as you might expect:

```
$('ul').children('li').appendTo('ul:first'); // move all LIs to the first UL
$('ul').not(':first').remove(); // delete the extra ULs
```

Customize the `'ul'` selector as needed; I recommend using a common class instead of a general tag selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/j76Lu/

Slightly more optimized (thanks, [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572859/901048)):

```
$('ul').not(':first').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/j76Lu/1/

or even better:

```
$('ul:gt(0)').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:eq(0)');
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/j76Lu/2/

Comment: @ahren, it would append them again, but wouldn't cause duplicates.

Comment: @gpojd - yeah I see that now, removed comment

Comment: Yeah, did'nt know you could actually remove the elements and in the next chain get the children. Never tried it before now ?

Comment: what if i want to combine/merge the `ul`s under a certain `li`? for example http://jsfiddle.net/T2z2H/ I want to merge the `ul`s under the second class

Comment: You should post a separate question with that new problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<ul />').append($('ul').remove().children('li')).appendTo('body');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4cRYf/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
var newUl = $('<ul>');    
$('ul').each(function() { 
       $(this).find('li').each(function() { 
            newUl.append($(this))
       });
       $(this).remove();
    });
$('selector').append(newUl);
```