# I need to insert a <ul> tag inside an specific class with childs. Tried with jquery selectors without success :(

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this one

```
            <ul id="reportsTree" class="tree">
              <li class="reportGroupItem">Coffee</li>
              <li class="reportGroupItem">Tea
                    <li class="reportItem">Black tea</li>
                    <li class="reportItem">Green tea</li>
              </li>
              <li class="reportGroupItem">Milk</li>
        </ul>
```

But I need this one

```
            <ul id="reportsTree" class="tree">
            <li class="reportGroupItem">Coffee</li>
            <li class="reportGroupItem">Tea
                <ul>
                    <li class="reportItem">Black tea</li>
                    <li class="reportItem">Green tea</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="reportGroupItem">Milk</li>
        </ul>
```

Look that the two <li_> elements with the class "reportItem" are wrapped by a  element... but I cannot just wrap "reportItem" elements with  because can be more than one (like the example) and I cannot just insert the  element after a "reportGroupItem" becasue maybe there are no childs inside... So, what can I do.

I've tried with .wrapInner(), .wrapAll, looking for first child...

Very easy, but very frustrating for me :(

Malformed code is generated like this:

```
                <logic:iterate name="ReportGenerationForm" property="reportGroups" id="group">
                <li class="reportGroupItem">
                    <bean:write name="group" property="code" /> 
                    <logic:iterate name="group" property="reports" id="report" indexId="index">
                        <li class="reportItem">
                            <bean:write name="report" property="code" />
                        </li>
                    </logic:iterate>
                </li>
            </logic:iterate>
```

Comment: How is the malformed HTML in the first example generated?

Comment: You could loop through all the `<li>` elements with a `for` loop. When you encounter a `reportItem`, you prepend a `<ul>`. When you encounter a `reportGroupItem` AND the previous item was a `reportItem`, then you append a `</ul>`.

Comment: _"and I cannot just insert the element after a "reportGroupItem" becasue maybe there are no childs inside"_ - I don't get what you mean by that. A reportItem alwys has to be in a reportGroupItem, no?

Comment: @CBroe yes, but if I wrap a ul for each "reportItem" I think I get <ul><li class="reportItem">Black tea</li></ul>
<ul><li class="reportItem">Green tea</li></ul>instead of <ul>
                    <li class="reportItem">Black tea</li>
                    <li class="reportItem">Green tea</li>
                </ul>

Comment: I think I wouldn't bother to try and get this done using any of the "wrap" methods, I think they are too generic for something like this. The browser will initially render this into a DOM that has all the LI on the same level. So I'd loop over the reportItems, and check if their parent is #reportsTree - if so, that means they will need to be appended to the UL inside the previous reportGroupItem. And if that UL does not exist yet, then it has to be created at this point first.

Comment: As noted above, but worth reiterating:  The browser will render this as a flat list with all the `li`s **at the same level**.   See [MDN li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) - "*The end tag can be omitted if the list item is immediately followed by another <li> element*" - so this **is valid HTML** (except the extra closing `</li>`) to generate a flat list.

Comment: You might be better to reframe your code in your "bean"?  When you output `<li class="reportItem">` add the `ul` here: `<ul class="reportList"><li class="reportItem"><ul>` then you can find `.reportList + .reportList` and combine them.

Comment: freedomn-m This was my first try buy I don't know how to do it. I don't know how can check if the "reportGroupItem" has childs or not during the render. I've tried using the "indexId" with no success.

Comment: I mean: always output the `ul` with `li.reportItem` (the inner) then use jquery to clean-up.  I've provided a more detailed answer to explain this.   I'm sure if you wanted a [tag:jsp] solution you could tag [tag:jsp] and someone would help you with that part (possibly as a new question so you don't get two solutions: jquery vs jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Reframing the question based on OPs comment *"this was my first try"*, by changing the source to output as:

```
<logic:iterate name="group" property="reports" id="report" indexId="index">
  <ul>
    <li class="reportItem">
      <bean:write name="report" property="code" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</logic:iterate>
```

which will output as:

```
<ul id="reportsTree" class="tree">
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Coffee</li>
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Tea
    <ul>
      <li class="reportItem">Black tea</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="reportItem">Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

We can then, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572781/2181514) combine the `li`s inside the inner `ul`s using:

```
  $("ul > li > ul + ul").each((i, e) => {
    $(e).children('li').appendTo($(e).prev());
    $(e).remove();
  })
```

you could use ids/classes instead, eg `ul#reportsTree > li.reportGroupItem > ul + ul`

which says: find all lists that follow another list inside a list item inside a list.  The key part is the `ul + ul`.  Similar would be `ul>li>ul:not(:first)`

Then moves all the children list items to the previous `ul` (no need for `.prev("ul")` or similar as the `ul+ul` already confirms previous is a ul)

Updated snippet below.  Here, I've given each `ul` and underline/separator so you can visibly see them combine when clicking the button.   Or you can inspect element to see the effect (and that there's no "orphaned"(childless) `ul` left behind)

```js
$("button").on("click", () => {
  $("ul>li>ul+ul").each((i, e) => {
    //console.log($(e).text())
    $(e).children('li').appendTo($(e).prev());
    $(e).remove();
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="reportsTree" class="tree">
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Coffee</li>
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Tea
    <ul>
      <li class="reportItem">Black tea</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="reportItem">Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="reportGroupItem">Milk</li>
</ul>
<button>
click me
</button>
```